# Adding two lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to add two lists : (1 2 3) and (5 3 4) should yield (6 5 7).
The function should add the elements on the corresponding position, so even if I would have (9 1 2)  +  ( 5 2 6) , it should yield (14 3 8).
  My function

```
(defun add(l r)
    (setf return-value '())
        (loop for i from 0 to (- (length l) 1)
            do (setf return-value (cons (+(nth i l)(nth i r)) return-value))
        )
    (reverse return-value)
)
```

How could I create a simmilar function which would subtract the lists ?

Comment: You've been asking an number of relatively basic Lisp questions, all on the same topic of working with lists of digits.  It might be better to sit down and work through some Lisp tutorials, or a good Lisp textbook.  Between this and your previous two questions, it seems like you're asking us to do a large portion of a project for you.  Even skimming through [14.1.2 Conses as Lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_ab.htm) and [14.2 The Conses Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_conses.htm) in the HyperSpec would help.

Comment: I have managed to create a subtraction function without using mapcar.
@Joshua , I studied your solutions and used them to solve my problem.
And yes, I originally asked about issues i ran into while working on a project, but I've got evertghing going. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @BogdanMolinger Why are you trying to avoid `mapcar` though?  The task is seems that you're trying to perform is simple if you use `mapcar`.  E.g., `(defun sum (x y) (digits->number (mapcar '+ x y)))` and `(defun difference (x y) (digits->number (mapcar '- x y)))` (where `digits->number` is as defined in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23876765/1281433) to your other question).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I figured that mapcar would work fine with adding two lists, and I can apply the `decompose` function on the result but it would be difficult to use mapcar for subtractions because I might get something like (-10 5 -16 8 9) which would be harder to normalize considering the borrowed carry.

Comment: What doesn't work about the carry?  With the code I provided, `(digits->number '(-5 2))` produces `15` (i.e., -5 + 20), and `(digits->number '(-10 5 -16 8 9))` produces `96440` (which I think is right).  Since you're really just evaluating a polynomial, it seems like it should work.  E.g., both `(digits->number (mapcar '- '(2 8 4) '(5 5 5)))` and `(- 482 555)` produce `-73`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Polynomial arithmetic

This seems like a follow up to your previous question, [Decompose a list of numbers into digits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23872701/1281433),.  There, you had a list of digits numbers, and they were the a<sub>i</sub> of a polynomial of the form

∑<sub>i=0…</sub> 10<sup>i</sup>a<sub>i</sub>

where the *n* numbers in your list are  the values of a<sub>0</sub> to a<sub>n-1</sub>, and everything after that is presumed to be zero.  You were asking for a way to normalize the values such that each a<sub>i</sub> was in the range [0,9].  [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23876765/1281433) to that question showed a few ways to do that.

Now, once you view numbers as a polynomial of this form, it's easy to see that you can simply piecewise add and subtract coefficients to the get the right, if not yet normalized, coefficients of the sum or difference.  E.g.,

378 = 8 + 7×10 + 3×100→ (8 7 3)
519 = 9 + 1×10 + 5×100→ (9 1 5)

The sum is simply

(8+9) + (7+1)×10 + (3+5)×100 →<sub>`(mapcar '+ x y)`</sub> (17 8 8) →<sub>`(number->digits (digits->number …))`</sub> (7 9 8)

The difference is simply

(8-9) + (7-1)×10 + (3-5)×100 →<sub>`(mapcar '- x y)`</sub> (-1 6 -2) →<sub>???</sub> ???

What we don't have here is an appropriate normalization procedure.  The one provided in the previous question doesn't work here.  However, the list of digits is still correct, insofar as coefficients go, and the `digits->number` procedure produces the correct value of -141.

So, while you'll need to rethink what it means to show a list of digits for a negative number, you can do the correct type of addition and subtraction on your lists with the following, as long as both lists have the same length.  If they don't have the same length, you'll need to pad the shorter one with zeros.  A reimplementation of `mapcar` that supports this sort of operation might be useful here.

```
(defun sum (x y)
  (mapcar '+ x y))

(defun difference (x y)
  (mapcar '- x y))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are allowed to use the standard functions, then [`mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) is your friend:

```
(mapcar #'+ '(1 2 3) (9 7 5))
==> (10 9 8)
```

Similarly for `-`.

Your function suffers from quadratic performance - you should not be using [`nth`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nth.htm).
You should also bind `return-value` with [`let`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm).
You should also use [`nreverse` instead of `reverse`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm) since you are constructing a fresh list anyway.

The more idiomatic way to write your function is

```
(defun addl (l r)
  (loop for x in l and y in r collect (+ x y)))
```