# Common Lisp - symbolic polynomial calculation

Tags: common-lisp, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I would like to perform some symbolic calculations on lisp.
I found useful derivative function and I would like to know how to write simple recursive function to add/substract/etc. polynomials.

Input (e.g.): `(addpolynomial '(+ (^ (* 2 x) 5) 3) '(+ (^ (* 3 x) 5) (^ (* 3 x) 2)))`

Output: `(+ (^ (* 5 x) 5) (^ (* 3 x) 2)) 3)`

Do you know how to do this?
Or maybe you know other symbolic calculation examples?

Comment: You might be helped by [Adding two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23878202/1281433).

Comment: That's not useful, I need to perform symbolic computation with representation polynomials as functions, nut numbers like `(3 . 4)`.

Comment: You're not showing anything with functions.  You've got lists like `'(+ (^ (* 2 x) 5) 3)`. The notation `(^ (* 2 x) 5)` is kind of odd, though. Do you really mean 2x raised to the fifth power?  Usually we'd write that [32 times [x to the 5th]], or in Lispy notation `(* 32 (^ x 5))`.  But most of this kind of polynomial arithmetic comes down to figuring out what the corresponding coefficients are.  That's why (^ (* 2 x) 5)` is really awkward to work with, but `(* 32 (^ x 5))` is pretty convenient.

Comment: You're right - bad example. However I'd like to add e.g. `(* 32 (^ x 5))` to `(* 2 (^ x 4))` and get `(+ (* 32 (^ x 5)) (* 2 (^ x 4)))` without any simplification (if applicable)

Comment: What hinders you from writing that yourself? Learn some basic Lisp and solve it yourself: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/ . It's relatively easy in Lisp develop a solution for that problem. Legions of students did that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've dealt with polynomials in Lisp in the past, I've used arrays of numbers (letting the variable be assumed, which means I couldn't trivially have things like "x*x + y", but since I didn't need that...).

That allows you to represent "2x^5 + 3" as `#(3 0 0 0 0 2)`, finding the factor of x^n by `(aref poly n)` and other handy operations.

This also allows you to define addition as simply `(map 'vector #'+ ...)` (multiplication requires a bit more work).